# There's a way to trigger multiple executions of the same test suite?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, puppeteer

There is a way to trigger an execution of a test suite multiple times.
I want to create a stress test and collect the results for analysis.
In order to do so, I prepared a test suite contained my desired test scenarios and randomized input data.

**Expected**

What I am looking for is an easy way to perform parallel executions of the same test suite to stress the application flow. Kind of a way to pass an argument saying how many thread executions of jest I want.

**Research**

At first, I was looking for some jest parameter to perform multiples execution but could not find what I want.

Looking for a CI/CD friendly solution.

Comment: Probably [test.concurrent.each](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testconcurrenteachtablename-fn-timeout) is what you're looking for

Comment: @Teneff that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you a lot!